# How to set Dragging movement directions UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, drag, uipangesturerecognizer, drop

[image]

i use Drag and Drop of UICollectionView to reoder item in collectionview
now preview draging item can move any on screen
mine expect to drag item that can move only horizontal in collectionview frame
how can i do it?

`collectionView.dragDelegate                  = self collectionView.dropDelegate                  = self collectionView.dragInteractionEnabled        = true`

i Trying to pangesture but it's not what i expected